# ios method param assign global variable

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Why ClassA NSMutableArray arl count is still 0?

Is there any way around this?

Class B

```
B.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import"A.h"

@interface B :NSObject
-(void) doSomeThing;
```

B.m

```
@implementation B

-(void)doSomeThing{
      NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
      A *a = [[A alloc] init];
     [a getValue:Array];
}
```

Class A

A.h

```
#import <UKit/UKit.h>
@class B;
@interface A :UIViewController;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arl;

-(void) getValue:(NSMutableArray *)Array;

-(IBAction)button:(id)sender;

@end
```

A.m

```
 @implementation A
 @synthesize arl;

 -(void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     B *b = [[B alloc] init];
    [b doSomeThing];
}

-(void) getValue:(NSMutableArray *) Array {

     arl = Array;
    // arl = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:Array];
    // [arl addObjectFromArray:Array];
    NSLog(@"arl count is :%d",[arl count]); // the log at here is 4
}

-(IBAction) button : (id)sender{
    NSLog(@"arl count is :%d",[arl count]);// the log at here is 0 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a new instance of `A` in `doSomething`. That instance is not the same as the instance that is connected to your `button:` method, whose `arl` is still uninitialized and therefore has no items in it, hence the count of zero when `button` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You create a A object first.When A's viewDidLoad,you create a B object.But when the B object call doSomeThing method,you create the other new A object again,**not equal to previous A object**.
And your button belongs to the first A object,the mutable array belongs to the second A object.
A little complicated,I hope you can understand.